# Чтение файла в массивы

Tags: массивы, delphi, файлы

Есть файл следующего содержания:

```
8 1 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
3
```

Первая строчка содержит два числа: размер первого и второго массива, вторая и третья строчки -- сами массивы.

Как в Delphi прочитать этот файл, чтобы записать первую строчку в переменные, а остальные две строки -- в два массива?

Comment: За тебя тут делать это не будут.
Или напиши на каком моменте у тебя возникла проблема или тема просто будет закрыта

Comment: Сам принцип чтения, как читать файл в массивы.

Comment: @akazerg, варианты:

 - В современном стиле через класс `TFileStream`.
 - В старом стиле через переменную типа `TextFile` и процедуры `AssignFile`, `Reset`, `ReadLn`, `CloseFile`.

Comment: Читаем первую строку.  
Из первой строки получаем размерности массивов.  
Задаем размерность массивов, полученную при чтении первой строки.

Из второй строки закидываем данные в массив 1.  
Из третьей строки закидываем данные в массив 2.

Answer (score 1):

В цикле построчно читаешь файл в массив. 
Если счетчик цикла равен 1, т.е. читаешь первую строчку, разбирай полученные данные и создавай массивы размерами, соответствующими значениям.
Если счетчик больше единицы, то разбирай полученные строки по одному значению и вноси их в массив, соответствующий счетчику-1.